# How do I render the various parts (like tags) of a blog post in Orchard CMS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, orchardcms

I'm trying to render the list of blog posts in this layout:

```
[first post - special summary]
[second post][third post][fourth post]
[pager]
```

I'm trying to render the first post myself and then loop over the remaining items to render them using the blog post summary template.

A number of questions here:

1. Is this a good way to pull off the
   layout I'm trying to achieve or
   should I start looking into creating
   a module?
2. Should I create a summary
   template for my special first post
   rendering and how would I go about
   that?
3. If I continue down the same
   path how do I render parts like tags
   and the postdate?

I have this so far in my theme: **Parts.Blogs.BlogPost.List-url-blog.cshtml**

```
@using Orchard.Blogs.Extensions;
@using Orchard.Blogs.Models;
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> blogPosts = Model.ContentItems;
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("content-items");
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("blog-posts");

    var firstPost = blogPosts.FirstOrDefault();
    //BlogPart blog = (BlogPart)firstPost.Get(typeof(BlogPart));

}
<h1>@firstPost.Title</h1>
by <span>@firstPost.ContentItem.CommonPart.Owner.NormalizedUserName</span>

@* How do i render tags using the tags part template? *@

@Display(firstPost.Tags) 
@Display(firstPost.Parts_Tags_ShowTags)
@Display(firstPost.TagsPart) 
@Display(firstPost.ContentItem.TagsPart)
@Display(firstPost.ContentItem.TagsPart.ContentItem)

@* none of the above work *@

<hr />
<ul class="content-items">
    @foreach (var post in blogPosts.Skip(1))
    {
        <li class="content-item-summary">
            @Display(post)
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Bonus points - Why can't I do something like this:

```
@Display(blogPosts.Skip(1))
```

but I can do

```
@Display(blogPosts)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, hi. Try this:

```
@using Orchard.Blogs.Extensions;
@using Orchard.Blogs.Models;
@using Orchard.ContentManagement;
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    IEnumerable<dynamic> blogPosts = Model.ContentItems;
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("content-items");
    Model.ContentItems.Classes.Add("blog-posts");

    var firstPost = blogPosts.FirstOrDefault();
    var otherPosts = blogPosts.Skip(1).ToList();
}
<h1>@firstPost.Title</h1>
by <span>@firstPost.ContentItem.CommonPart.Owner.NormalizedUserName</span>

@Display(New.MyTagShape(Tags: firstPost.ContentItem.TagsPart.CurrentTags))

<hr />
@Display(New.List().AddRange(otherPosts))
```

And then this is the code for MyTagShape.cshtml:

```
Here are your tags:
<ul>
@foreach (var tag in Model.Tags) {
    <li>@tag.TagName</li>
}
</ul>
```

Works on my machine.
But as I was saying on the forums, you might want to customize the summary templates rather than the whole list.

Edit: here is how you would create a different template for the first item: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/05/23/orchard-list-customization-first-item-template.aspx

Comment: Oh and those classes are now going nowhere, you might want to move them to the new list shape, which I neglected to do.